# How to get user name using new @assistant/conversation sdk

Tags: actions-on-google

In the old [actions-on-google sdk](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs) .I can ask the permission to get user name,
I couldn't find any documentation on how to do this in the new [@assistant/conversataion sdk](https://actions-on-google.github.io/assistant-conversation-nodejs/3.6.0/index.html), is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you perform [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/assistant/identity/google-sign-in#access_profile_information_in_your_backend) you will have access to user information including their name.